# Vectorizing multiple nested loops containing circshift in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, performance, nested, vectorization, permutation

I would like to increase the performance of my operation containing multiple nested loops. The operation is supposed to give me all possible combinations of sums for 4 matrices. Currently, I am using circshift for this as follows:

```
for ss = 1:max_n_steps+1 % max steps + possibility of NO STEP!!
    for tt = 1:max_n_steps+1
        for uu = 1:max_n_steps+1
            curr_perm = horzcat(curr_perm, curr_first + circshift(curr_second, ss-1, 2) + circshift(curr_third, tt-1, 2) + circshift(curr_fourth, uu-1, 2));
        end
    end
end
```

This goes through all four matrices (curr_first, curr_second etc.), sums them up, and concatenates them with the previous combinations. It results in a satisfactory array of all possible sums of columns. However, the more loops I introduce (e.g. when I have 5 matrices instead of 4), this takes more and more time. Is there a possibility to vectorize this process? I saw things like bsxfun being used, but don't know how to apply them here.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please show an input and output data example?

Comment: Sure, sorry for not doing that right away: This is the input, a 4-dimensional matrix: https://pastebin.com/mGEM5Xa5. The four dimensions are curr_first, curr_second etc. The output is too large to paste unfortunately, but consists of 16^4 columns and as many rows as each of the four initial matrices. 16 is max_n_steps+1.

Comment: Edit your question to include code instead of pasting links. Then it is self contained, without users having to navigate to external sites like pastebin.

Comment: Instead of using pasting the real data, it would be more useful if you gave a small input example, e.g. 3x2x4 matrix with the expected output. "...all possible combinations of sums for 4 matrices" is a bit vague to understand what exactly you want to do

Comment: The array in the linked pastebin is 3D, not 4D, and contains a lot of repeated rows. Why don’t you add to your question the two lines of code you need to create that matrix? That way it will be self-contained and your question won’t become useless when the pastebin is deleted. Plus, it gives more insight into the problem. Right now it is hard to see the structure in that data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main inefficiency in your starting point isn't that it uses loops rather than vector operations, but that it recomputes calls to `circshift` with the same matrix and the same offset many many times over. For example, your expression `circshift(curr_second, ss-1, 2)` only changes when `ss` changes, but is evaluated at every iteration of the inner loops:

```
for tt = 1:max_n_steps+1
    for uu = 1:max_n_steps+1
```

even though `curr_second` and `ss` don't change throughout those loops.

You can avoid this by evaluating all the possible shifts of each matrix and then adding permutations of these shifts by indexing into these results:

```
curr_second_shifts = nan([size(curr_second) max_n_steps+1]);
curr_third_shifts  = nan([size(curr_third ) max_n_steps+1]);
curr_fourth_shifts = nan([size(curr_fourth) max_n_steps+1]);

for ii = 1:max_n_steps+1
    curr_second_shifts(:,:,ii) = circshift(curr_second, ii-1, 2);
    curr_third_shifts( :,:,ii) = circshift(curr_third,  ii-1, 2);
    curr_fourth_shifts(:,:,ii) = circshift(curr_fourth, ii-1, 2);
end

for ss = 1:max_n_steps+1
    for tt = 1:max_n_steps+1
        for uu = 1:max_n_steps+1
            curr_perm = horzcat(curr_perm, curr_first + ...
                                           curr_second_shifts(:,:,ss) + ...
                                           curr_third_shifts( :,:,tt) + ...
                                           curr_fourth_shifts(:,:,uu));
         end
    end
end
```

To fully vectorize this, you can store the different shifts of each matrix along a different dimension; MATLAB's singleton expansion will then fill this n-dimensional array with the relevant permutations when adding.

```
curr_second_shifts = nan([size(curr_second) max_n_steps+1]);
curr_third_shifts  = nan([size(curr_third ) 1 max_n_steps+1]);
curr_fourth_shifts = nan([size(curr_fourth) 1 1 max_n_steps+1]);

for ii = 1:max_n_steps+1
    curr_second_shifts(:,:,ii)     = circshift(curr_second, ii-1, 2);
    curr_third_shifts( :,:,1,ii)   = circshift(curr_third,  ii-1, 2);
    curr_fourth_shifts(:,:,1,1,ii) = circshift(curr_fourth, ii-1, 2);
end

curr_perm = curr_first  + ...
            curr_second_shifts + ...
            curr_third_shifts  + ...
            curr_fourth_shifts);
```

Then to get all the permutations arranged on the higher dimensions back into the original series of columns just reindex with 2 being the highest dimension:

```
curr_perm = curr_perm(:,:);
```

However this can be further vectorized to eliminate separate variables per matrix, which will be important the more dimensions you have to add to these permutations. Let's define `curr` to be a 3D matrix such that:

```
curr = cat(3,curr_first,curr_second,curr_third,curr_fourth);
```

Then all the shifts can be calculated with one call to `circshift` per offset:

```
curr_shift = nan([size(curr(:,:,2:end)) max_n_steps+1]);

for ii = 1:max_n_steps+1
    curr_shift(:,:,:,ii) = circshift(curr(:,:,2:end), ii-1, 2);
end
```

and then permuting with increasing numbers of singleton dimensions before adding:

```
curr_perm = curr_first;

for ii = 1:size(curr_shift,3)
    curr_perm = curr_perm + permute(curr_shift(:,:,ii,:),[1:3 5:(ii+3) 4]);
end

curr_perm = curr_perm(:,:);
```

For MATLAB earlier than R2016b, the expansion will not happen implicitly and you will need `bsxfun` as you suggest:

```
for ii = 1:size(curr_shift,3)
    curr_perm = bsxfun(@plus, curr_perm, permute(curr_shift(:,:,ii,:),[1:3 5:(ii+3) 4]);
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I will try that!

Comment: Fantastic answer!